# Local diffeomorphisms as isomorphisms on stalks

Tags: differential-geometry, sheaf-theory, smooth-manifolds

The [stacks project](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01HA) says that a smooth map $f:M\rightarrow N$ naturally gives rise to an arrow between the sheaves of smooth functions. I don't understand how this fits in with the notion of a local diffeomorphism: a local diffeo is a smooth map whose germs are diffeomorphisms. If every such arrow induced (and was induced from) an arrow of sheaves, then every local diffeo would be a global diffeo.

What am I missing?

Comment: Well, your reasoning must be wrong. But what is your reasoning? Give some details.

Comment: @ZhenLin I was thinking that each smooth map of manifolds is induced by the morphism of sheaves it induces, hence, every smooth map "comes" from a morphism of sheaves and local isos lift to global ones.

Comment: I'm sorry, but that is rather vague. You need to be more precise. Perhaps in doing so you will find your own error.